# Android application open youtube video URI.parse

Tags: android, youtube

I'm trying to call a youtube video from android application when i click on a imagebutton, but when i call the function, it stop my application.

This is my code:

```
    public void btnVideoAssinante_Onclick(View view) {
    String id = "Aw4OVDhEuvU";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
    intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", id);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit (following first comment):** Rename your function to `btnVideoAssinante_OnClick` instead of `btnVideoAssinante_Onclick`.

Note the capital C in `Click`.

Comment: 05-13 08:48:32.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1331): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method btnVideoAssinante_OnClick(View) in the activity class com.polifrete.polifreteandroid.ComoFuncionaMotActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'imgMot02'

Comment: OMG, this was a stupid mistake i've made... Realy so sorry! And thanks!